# Make certain fields in entity not be saved to the database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations, entity

I am learning Spring and Hibernate. I prepared the entity of an image. The fields are succesfullu saved to the database as column names, but I need that some of properties to exist in the entity but not be saved to database. But the actually are being saved. I tried to remove a @Column annotation or use `@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)` but not succeed. Always got the columns in the database with null value. So how to prevent Spring and Hibernate from create columns of certain fields. I am trying to do it with the fields `size`, `width` and `height`.

*Code of the entity:*

```
package tk.trzczy.gallery.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Date;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@Entity
@Table(name = "images")
public class Image {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "mySeqGen6", sequenceName = "mySeq6", initialValue = 11, allocationSize = 100)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "mySeqGen6")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 300)
    private String title;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String url;

    @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Long width;

    @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Long height;

    @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Dimension size;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="image_category_id")
    private ImageCategory imageCategory;

    @Column(name="datecreated", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    private Date dateCreated;

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        dateCreated = new Date();
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public Date getDateCreated() {
        return dateCreated;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public void setDateCreated(Date dateCreated) {
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }

    public Image() {}

    public Image(Integer id, String title, String url) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Post{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", url='" + url + '\'' +
                ", date=" + dateCreated +
                '}';
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public ImageCategory getImageCategory() {
        return imageCategory;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    public void setImageCategory(ImageCategory imageCategory) {
        this.imageCategory = imageCategory;
    }

    public long getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(long width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public long getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(long height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public Dimension getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(Dimension size) {
        this.size=size;
    }
}
```

*pom.xml*

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>tk.trzczy</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <aspect.version>1.9.2</aspect.version>
        <jackson.version>2.9.8</jackson.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.4.2.Final</hibernate.version>
        <hibernate.validator.version>5.2.1.Final</hibernate.validator.version>
        <c3p0.version>0.9.5.2</c3p0.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- servlets and jps -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>jboss</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--hibernate-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate-C3P0 Integration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- c3p0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${c3p0.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for rest services -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For Aop -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspect.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspect.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- To Send Email -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--logging-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- PostgreSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-taglibs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-war-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-rest-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- To define the plugin version in your parent POM -->
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!-- To use the plugin goals in your POM or parent POM -->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>



            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Try the JPA [`@Transient`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/2.2/apidocs/javax/persistence/Transient.html) annotation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

transient is a Java keyword which marks a member variable not to be serialized when it is persisted to streams of bytes.

`@Transient` annotation in JPA or Hibernate is used to indicate that a field is not to be persisted or ignore fields to save in the database. @Transient exist in javax. persistence package. It is used to annotate a property or field of an entity class, mapped superclass, or embeddable class.

hence mark the Field as `@Transient`.

Answer (score 0):

@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
private transient Long width;

use this transient keyword to prevent these fields from being persisted into your DB, it works.